# Trouble with fitch and the use of existential elimination rule

Tags: fitch

[image: I am wondering why fitch is not allowing me to use existential elimination for this final step]

I am wondering why fitch is not allowing me to use existential elimination for this final step

Comment: Because Existential elimination needs a **new** constant.

Comment: The solution is simple: you have to swap the initial Existential-elim with the Universal-elim.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, the name used to instantiate Existential-elim should not appear in any undischarged assumptions but line 3 is not. Why do you think a new constant is necessary in this case ? Perhaps, this proof system has a slight different requirement.

Comment: @F.Zer - please, re-read the [ND quantifier rules](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7): "In case of (forall I) and (exists E) a parameter **a** is required to be “fresh” in the sense of having no other occurrences in **Gamma , Delta, phi, psi**."

Comment: Thank you, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA ! I re-read the article you linked. In page 383 of "forall X" book, the requirement for both rules is: "c must not occur in any undischarged assumption". What do you think is the difference between the link you provided and this ? Are they saying essential the same but with different words? I will appreciate your insight.

Comment: @F.Zer - maybe the sw has only detected that term **c**used for Existential-elim was not "new"...

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro Allegranza. I am now seeing p.357 of the book Language, Proof and Logic (this software is based on it), and for the rule of Existential Elimination the requirement is, as you say, "Where **c** does not occur outside the subproof where it is introduced." This book doesn't mention the word _undischarged_ (as the link you posted).

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account Mauro suggestion in the comments, you will need a fresh constant (does not appear previously in the proof), for using Existential Elimination. So, I think this would be correct.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is valid. Local term `c` is properly isolated to its context.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my answer, @Graham Kemp !